# Microsoft Access - Creating a Query based on the Results of Another Query

Tags: ms-access

This query generates a table of customer id's:

```
SELECT Transactions.customerId
FROM Transactions 
WHERE Transactions.purchaseDate <#9/1/2012#
GROUP BY Transactions.customerId
HAVING  Sum(Transactions.amountPaid)<>0;
```

This query generates a table of transactions:

```
SELECT Customers.firstName, Customers.lastName, Transactions.transactionId, Transactions.product, Transactions.purchaseDate, Transactions.amountPaid, Customers.customerId
FROM Customers INNER JOIN Transactions ON Customers.customerId = Transactions.customerId
WHERE (((Transactions.refundTransaction)=False));
```

I want to select all of the transactions (second query) from only users generated by the first query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using MS Access, it is possible to save both of these queries and then add them by query name to the query design window. Once added, you can create an INNER JOIN between the two queries by dragging and dropping the relevant field name from one to the other. The next stage, if you can to move on, is to substitute the query name for a derived table, that is, the sql content of the query.

For example:

Query1

```
SELECT ID, CustName FROM Table1 WHERE SomeField > 2
```

Query2

```
SELECT CustID, TranName FROM Table2 WHERE SomeField > Date()
```

Query3

```
SELECT * FROM Query1 INNER JOIN Query2 ON Query1.ID = Query2.CustID
```

Substituting:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT ID, CustName 
   FROM Table1 
   WHERE SomeField > 2) As Q1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT CustID, TranName 
   FROM Table2 WHERE SomeField > Date()) As Q2
ON Q1.ID = Q2.CustID
```

Comment: This did the trick. Now I just have to find how Access combines both of the saved queries so it's not so sloppy. Thanks for your help.